# Can I search for values in two different type of arrays with just one type of variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm quite new to Java and I've been asked to create a program in which the user is able to input two values and store them in separate arrays. The two values I'm asking the user are name and cell number, then I must allow the user to search by typing either a name or a cell number and return the corresponding name or cell number. I made it possible to input the values and search within them by number but when I try searching by name I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "B"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW {
  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static int i, x = 2;
  static String names[] = new String[x];
  static int numbers[] = new int[x];
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Input();
    Compare();
  }
  public static void Input() {
    System.out.println("Enter a name followed by the persons number");
    while (i < x) {
      System.out.println("NAME: ");
      names[i] = sc.next();
      System.out.println("NUMBER: ");
      numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
      i++;
    }
  }
  public static void Compare() {
    System.out.println("=======SEARCH=======\nSEARCH CRITERIA: ");
    var temp = sc.next();
    System.out.println("NAME\tNUMBER");
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      if ((names[i].equals(temp)) || (numbers[i] == Integer.parseInt(temp.trim()))) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + numbers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You have to figure out if it is a name or cell number *before* you enter the loop. And I'd create separate loops, one for the name and one for the cell number. And while we're at it: always keep your UI code (printing / scanning / initial input validation) and business code separate.

Comment: Also Java coding conventions have methods and variables beginning with a lower-case letter, while classes begin with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the highest number that can be represented as an int in Java is 2147483647 (214-748-3647).  This clearly will not be able to hold a high enough number to accommodate any phone number.  To address this issue and also fix your main error, I would suggest storing the numbers as a string instead.  Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int x = 2;
    static String names[] = new String[x];
    static String numbers[] = new String[x];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
        compare();
    }

    public static void input() {
        System.out.println("Enter a name followed by the persons number");
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.println("NAME: ");
            names[i] = sc.next();
            System.out.println("NUMBER: ");
            numbers[i] = sc.next();
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void compare() {
        System.out.println("=======SEARCH=======\nSEARCH CRITERIA: ");
        String temp = sc.next();

        System.out.println("NAME\tNUMBER");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if ((names[i].equals(temp)) || numbers[i].equals(temp)) {
                System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("===END OF SEARCH====")
    }
}
```

Please also note that I un-defined your variable i.  As far as I can see there's no reason for you to be defining it.  Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem statement it doesn't seem like you need to do any additional processing on numbers. Hence, even if you store the number as a string it should be fine in this case.
Hence after getting a user search criteria, you could do a simple string search within both arrays.

Hope this helps :)